# Passing a String from one method to another method

Tags: java, android

I need to pass a String from one method to another method and now I'm a bit clueless.

The String values (callbackURL & donationId) I want to pass are inside this method:

```
public void postData() {
.
.
.
.
            String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
            String donationId = tokens.nextToken();
                
    }
```

and I want to pass the values to another method, let's say it's called `private examplePayment()`. How am I able to perform that?

Comment: Seriously, if you are this green don't start with android. Start with Plain Old Java and when you have some background to it begin playing with android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public void postData(){
.
.
.
.
      String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
      String donationId = tokens.nextToken();
      examplePayment(callbackURL, donationId);
}

private void examplePayment(String callback, String donationid){
      //deal with your callback and donationid variables
}
```

Comment: but how is it able to read that the String is from postData() method??

Comment: it is not reading the string, you are explicitly passing it to the examplePayment() method.

Answer (score 3):

You pass values to another method by declaring the parameters in the method signature, for example:

```
private void examplePayment(String callbackURL, String donationId) {
  //your logic in here
}
```

Then you can call it in your code like so:

```
public void postData() {
   String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
   String donationId = tokens.nextToken();
   examplePayment(callbackURL, donationId);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
public void postData() {
            String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
            String donationId = tokens.nextToken();

           examplePayment(callbackURL,donationId);
    } 
private void examplePayment(String callbackURL,String donationId){


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You mean you want to pass the strings to the function as arguments?

```
public void postData() {
   .
   .
   . 
   String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
   String donationId = tokens.nextToken();
   examplePayment(callbackURL, donationId);
}
.
.
.
private void examplePayment(String callbackURL, String donationId) {
    .
    . 
    .
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public String postData() {
   String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
   String someID = tokens.nextToken();
   this.examplePayment(callbackURL, someID);
}

OR
private examplePayment(String callbackURL, String someID){
    //   DO whatever you want with callback and someID
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Why dont you create method with arguments eg 
create a method like the following

```
private examplePayment(String callbackURL, String donationId){

...do your work

}
```

while calling you can pass arguments in postData method

```
public void postData() {
.
.
.
.
            String callbackURL = tokens.nextToken();
            String donationId = tokens.nextToken();
            examplePayment(callbackURL, donationId);// call the mthod
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class StringTest{    
    public void postData() {
        String callbackURL = "abc.cde.com";
        String donationId = "1233445";
        examplePayment(callbackURL,donationId);
    } 

    private void examplePayment(String pStrCallbackURL , String pStrDonationId){
        System.out.println("Callback url"+ pStrCallbackURL );
        System.out.println("DonationId "+ pStrDonationId );
    }
}
```

Now if you want to enable your examplePayment method to know which method is sending the strings , then add another method parameter , say "pCallingMethod" .

The method will look like

```
private void examplePayment(String pStrCallbackURL , String pStrDonationId , pStrCallingMethod){        
    System.out.println("Callback url"+ pStrCallbackURL );
    System.out.println("DonationId "+ pStrDonationId );
            System.out.println("Calling Method"+ pStrCallingMethod);
}
```

Pass the `CallingMethodName` as parameter to this method whenever you call `examplePayment()`.

This can be a solution.