# How do i use scanner input from another method as a variable in another method

Tags: java, variables, parameters

I have to refer to the users input name in the second method an I don't know if it is possible . What i have right prompts me to enter the name agin. also sorry if this is a dumb question i just started to code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
 Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    getName(keyboard);
    getRounds(keyboard,getName());

public static String getName(Scanner keyboard ) {
    System.out.print("Welcome to ROCK PAPER SCISSORS. I, Computer, will be your opponent.\n");
    System.out.print("Please type in your name and press return: ");
    String name = keyboard.next();
    System.out.print("\nWelcome " + name + ".");

    return name;
}

public static int getRounds(Scanner keyboard, Sting getName) {
    System.out.println();
    System.out.print("\nAll right"+getname+ "How many rounds would you like to play?\n");

    System.out.print("Enter the number of rounds you want to play and press return: ");
    
    int rounds = keyboard.nextInt();

    return rounds;
```

Comment: By the way, use ALL CAPS in a name only if a [constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constant_(computer_programming)). Mutable variables should be named using [lower camel case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camel_case)

Comment: Your Question needs a rewrite. That first sentence in unintelligible. Also, post tho code calling these two methods.

Comment: Duplicate of [*Passing a String from one method to another method*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8614365/642706).

Comment: Sorry fo the messy post it's my first time using this website so i wasn't sure how to use it . Ive updated it to make it easier to read and make my question more clear.

Comment: By the way, as a beginner, try to avoid using `static`. Using `static` is not object-oriented.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning a reference to a `String` object from your `getName` method. Good.

But then you neglected to capture that returned value. Bad.

```
String name = getName( keyboard );
```

This is just like what you did when you captured the returned reference from `new Scanner(System.in)` and stored that reference in a variable named `keyboard`. (By the way, “keyboard” is not the best name there, “scanner” or “console” is more appropriate.)

Then pass that reference to your `getRounds` method.

```
getRounds( keyboard , name );
```

This is just like what you did when you pass `keyboard` to the same method.

---

Before posting here, study [*The Java Tutorials*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) provided free-of-cost by Oracle Corp.